# Rearranging a 3-D array using indices from sorting?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, for-loop, vectorization, pytorch

I have a 3-D array of random numbers of size `[channels = 3, height = 10, width = 10]`.

[image]
Then I sorted it using sort command from pytorch along the columns and obtained the indices as well.

[image]

The corresponding index is shown below:

[image]

Now, I would like to return to the original matrix using these indices. I currently use `for` loops to do this (without considering the batches). The code is:

```
import torch
torch.manual_seed(1)
ch = 3
h = 10
w = 10
inp_unf = torch.randn(ch,h,w)
inp_sort, indices  = torch.sort(inp_unf,1)
resort = torch.zeros(inp_sort.shape)

for i in range(ch):
    for j in range(inp_sort.shape[1]):
        for k in range (inp_sort.shape[2]):
            temp = inp_sort[i,j,k]
            resort[i,indices[i,j,k],k] = temp
```

I would like it to be vectorized considering batches as well i.e.input size is `[batch, channel, height, width]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using [`Tensor.scatter_()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_)

You can directly scatter the sorted tensor back into its original state using the indices provided by `sort()`:

```
torch.zeros(ch,h,w).scatter_(dim=1, index=indices, src=inp_sort)
```

The intuition is based on the previous answer below. As `scatter()` is basically the reverse of `gather()`, `inp_reunf = inp_sort.gather(dim=1, index=reverse_indices)` is the same as `inp_reunf.scatter_(dim=1, index=indices, src=inp_sort)`:

---

#### Previous answer

***Note***: while correct, this is probably less performant, as calling the `sort()` operation a 2nd time.

You need to obtain the sorting "*reverse indices*", which can be done by "*sorting the indices returned by `sort()`*".

In other words, given `x_sort, indices = x.sort()`,  you have `x[indices] -> x_sort` ; while what you want is `reverse_indices` such that `x_sort[reverse_indices] -> x`.

This can be obtained as follows: `_, reverse_indices = indices.sort()`.

```python
import torch
torch.manual_seed(1)
ch, h, w = 3, 10, 10
inp_unf = torch.randn(ch,h,w)

inp_sort, indices = inp_unf.sort(dim=1)
_, reverse_indices = indices.sort(dim=1)
inp_reunf = inp_sort.gather(dim=1, index=reverse_indices)

print(torch.equal(inp_unf, inp_reunf))
# True
```